# How can I speed up my initialisation in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, promise

My app makes a lot of promise network calls (with $resource) when my app first starts up, so it takes a while for everything to load up. I thought this just might be the limitations of clientside on the first load, so I began thinking about using a orchestration layer with node to preload my data after the user logins. However, before I go down that rabbit hole, I wanted to see what other things could I do to improve speed.

Edit: The data requires authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data which is not hidden behind an authentication layer managed by your Angular app, you can condense your XHR requests into a plain `<script>` and get your server to provide the reference data before Angular executes.

```
<script src="//api/referenceData"></script>
<script src="//angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I love this answer and it saves me the hassle of having to preload, but I forgot to mention it has to be authenticated first.

Comment: Then it looks like the next best thing is reconfiguring your backend to return data in a single call rather than several. The orchestration layer could help, depending on how many http requests are made and what the size of the data that needs to be preloaded is?